# Can't put MongoDB in my PATH

Tags: mongodb, shell

I'm trying to include MongoDB in my `PATH` on Ubuntu 14.04 by issuing this command:

```
export PATH=/home/<my-user-name>/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1404-3.2.4/bin:$PATH
```

It seems OK but when I restart the terminal it can't find it again. Do you have any idea what's going on?

Comment: Where do you do this `export`? In a startup script of your system or shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

export commands only work for the current terminal window.
You should add this command to one of the files that run when you start your terminal session.
Your best choice would be to add this line to a file called ~/.profile, since it will run regardless of the shell you are using.

Comment: Thanks it worked! You just have to Logout and Login again!

Comment: If you want to skip the logout login step just run this command -
`source ~/.profile`, it will run the file and instantly apply all of the changes you did in it.